# Adjust vertical space between question title and text in exam class

Tags: spacing, exam

How do I adjust the vertical space between the question titles and the text of the questions in the `exam`-class.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\qformat{\large\textbf{Question \thequestion}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
    Some text
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I've tried adding some `\vspace` to the end of the argument of `\qformat` but that doesn't work. I can't figure out what controls the spacing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format provided with the `qformat` marco is injected in a horizontal box; that's why `\vspace` is not working.

To add vertical space after the question, one option is to add depth to the box, for instance with:

```
\qformat{
    \large\textbf{Question \thequestion}
    \hfill
    \vrule depth 1em width 0pt % Large depth to make space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could patch the macro responsible for issuing `\item`, adding `\\*[<length>]` at the end of it, with `\mbox{}` in order to make LaTeX think that some text actually follows.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\qformat{\textbf{\large Question \thequestion}\hfill}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\item@points@pageinfo}
  {\mbox{}\\*[2ex]}% <---- use the length you prefer
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question \lipsum[2]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]