# Add spacing after qformat question in exam

Tags: exam

I have a custom `qformat` in my exam class for the question title.
For questions which have text, I want their to be space between the question and the text.
`\vspace` does not seem to work, and from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353157/200609) `\vrule depth 2cm width 0pt` only seems to work properly if I put it in the `qformat`, which I do not want to do because I have some questions with text and some without - the ones without will then have too much space between the question part and the question title.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}

% supposed to have a \newpage and different spacing between ones with no question text and ones with question text.
\newcommand{\newquestion}{\question}
% There should be a command which works and adds sapce.
%\newcommand{\newquestionwithtext}{\newquestion????}

\begin{questions}
% vpsace just doesn't seem to work.
\newquestion\vspace{5cm}
Small Sister is a character in Orge Georwell's book 4891. They famously use the quote "Happy is sad. Is this loss? Lorem Ipsus".

\begin{parts}
\part[2] Explain how the rapid inflation following the big bang has affected the intertextuality of 4891.
\end{parts}

% This adds space between the first line and the second line.
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353157/200609, it works in qformat but that's not a solution for me.
\newquestion\vrule depth 2cm width 0pt
Small Sister is a character in Orge Georwell's book 4891. They famously use the quote "Happy is sad. Is this loss? Lorem Ipsus".
\begin{parts}
\part[2] Explain how the rapid inflation following the big bang has affected the intertextuality of 4891.
\end{parts}

\newquestion
% This spacing is fine.

\begin{parts}
\part[2] How do you count to 3?
\end{parts}


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redefined `\newquestion`  as `\newquestion{<vertical space>}` to add some vertical blank space after the custom `\qformat` and before the text.

For a question without text just `\question` works fine.

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}

\newcommand{\newquestion}[1]{\question\parbox[t][#1]{\linewidth}{}\par}% changed <<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \newquestion{5cm} % adds 5cm of blank space     
        Small Sister is a character in Orge Georwell's book 4891. They famously use the quote "Happy is sad. Is this loss? Lorem Ipsus".
        
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] Explain how the rapid inflation following the big bang has affected the intertextuality of 4891.
        \end{parts}     
        
        \newquestion{2cm} % adds 2cm of blank space     
        Small Sister is a character in Orge Georwell's book 4891. They famously use the quote "Happy is sad. Is this loss? Lorem Ipsus".
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2]  Explain how the rapid inflation following the big bang has affected the intertextuality of 4891.
        \end{parts}
        
        \question % normal question, no space added
        
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] How do you count to 3?
        \end{parts}     
        
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```